# Swift: isEmpty property for an array in a card game

Tags: arrays, swift, is-empty

I am working on my war card game app, and came up with this method. These are two arrays, first one filled with 52 cards, second is empty. Below there is a loop which removes a random card from first array, adds it to the second array.

```
 var cardsImg: [String] = ["2_of_clubs","2_of_hearts","2_of_diamonds","2_of_spades","3_of_clubs","3_of_diamonds","3_of_spades","3_of_hearts","4_of_diamonds","4_of_clubs","4_of_spades","4_of_hearts","5_of_spades","5_of_diamonds","5_of_hearts","5_of_clubs","6_of_clubs","6_of_diamonds","6_of_spades","6_of_hearts","7_of_clubs","7_of_diamonds","7_of_spades","7_of_hearts","8_of_hearts","8_of_clubs","8_of_spades","8_of_diamonds","9_of_spades","9_of_diamonds","9_of_clubs","9_of_hearts","10_of_hearts","10_of_clubs","10_of_diamonds","10_of_spades","jack_of_spades","jack_of_hearts","jack_of_diamonds","jack_of_clubs","queen_of_spades","queen_of_clubs","queen_of_hearts","queen_of_diamonds","king_of_spades","king_of_clubs","king_of_diamonds","king_of_hearts","ace_of_spades","ace_of_hearts","ace_of_clubs","ace_of_diamonds"]
var cardsImgEmpty: [String] = []

var upperLimit: UInt32 = 52
var randomNum: Int

for _ in 1...52 {
    randomNum = Int((arc4random_uniform(upperLimit)))
    cardsImgEmpty.append(cardsImg[randomNum])
    cardsImg.remove(at: randomNum)
    upperLimit -= 1
}

player1Card.image = UIImage(named: cardsImgEmpty[0])
player2Card.image = UIImage(named: cardsImgEmpty[1])
```

The idea is, when all the cards from cardsImg are used, and this array is empty, game ends and label displays a winner based on the number of points between the players. Below is the function that i created which is supposed to disable a Draw button after the second array is filled with 52 objects and print a winner into a label. But when running a test, game ends based on the results of the first draw. What should be changed or added in order to make the game end only after all cards have been used up once?

```
 func gameOver() {
        if cardsImg.isEmpty {
        draw.isEnabled = false
            let player1FinalScore = Int(player1Score.text!)!
            let player2FinalScore = Int(player2Score.text!)!
            if player1FinalScore > player2FinalScore {
                winner.text = "Player 1 wins!"
            } else {
                winner.text = "Player 2 wins!"
            }
        }
    }
gameOver()
```

Comment: well, after you shuffle cardsImgEmpty contains all the data and cardsImg is empty.

Comment: There's a function to shuffle arrays in GameKit btw : var shuffled = GKARC4RandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: arrayToShuffle) Save you worrying about 2 arrays

Comment: i see the problem, but how can i fix it so it would be possible to end the game after each card have been used once?

Comment: Looking at the explanation, calling gameOver() in didSet property observer of first array should help.